# Need help in creating simple ledger from mysql debt & credit tables?

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

How to create below customer ledger using above tables. Ledger should be ORDER by Date as i did in below in Ms word below. Please help(Using PHP) i tried inner join but nothing fruitful date make it more difficult for me.
[image]

Comment: can u give me your .sql file to import for experiment?

Comment: yes for sure but how to send?

Comment: got the solution posting below as answer may be you need to tweak at some level like field name, table name etc.

Comment: This is years old but, just an advice on creating database tables. It seems the two tables that you made is identical to each other. Instead of creating 2 tables just make one table. Then add another column like "table_type" it would be 'credit' or 'debit' to identify the differences.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

to print the table it can be something similar to follow using the array prepared as final array

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Customer Ledger(<?php echo $rearrangedFinalData[0]['customer'] ?>)</h1>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Date</td>
            <td>Invoice No</td>
            <td>Debit</td>
            <td>Credit</td>
            <td>Balance</td>
        </tr>
        <?php 
        //initialize balance as per your requirement
        $balance = 0;
        foreach($rearrangedFinalData AS $row) {
         ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['date'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['invoice'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['debit'] > 0 ? $row['debit'] : '' ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['credit'] > 0 ? $row['credit'] : '' ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $balance = ($balance + $row['debit'] - $row['credit']) ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: MAN you made my day, love you

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
$CONNECTION = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','laravel');
$debitTable = 'debt';
$creditTable = 'credit';
$finalData = array();

// get debt data
$queryOfDebt = mysqli_query($CONNECTION,"select * from ".$debitTable." order by Db_date");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryOfDebt)) {
    $finalData[$row['cust_name']][] = $row;
}
// get credit data
$queryOfCredit = mysqli_query($CONNECTION,"select * from ".$creditTable." order by cr_date");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryOfCredit)) {
    $finalData[$row['cust_name']][] = $row;
}

// rearrange all data with date
$rearrangedFinalData = array();
foreach($finalData AS $first) {
    foreach($first AS $data) {
        $temp = array();
        $temp['date'] = isset($data['Db_date']) ? $data['Db_date'] : $data['cr_date'];
        $temp['invoice'] = isset($data['dm_invoice']) ? $data['dm_invoice'] : $data['Invoice_no'];
        $temp['credit'] = isset($data['cr_amount']) ? $data['cr_amount'] : 0;
        $temp['debit'] = isset($data['Debt_amount']) ? $data['Debt_amount'] : 0;
        $temp['customer'] = $data['cust_name'];
        $rearrangedFinalData[] = $temp;
    }
}
usort($rearrangedFinalData,function($a,$b){
        return strtotime($a['date']) > strtotime($b['date']);
});
var_dump($rearrangedFinalData);
```

consider the rearrangedFinalData will hold all the table entries, you can calculate balance based on either credit is set or debit is set in final array
consider updating table or column name based on your requirement

Comment: Bundle of thanks Sam, i did few changes like add WHERE clause for customer name as i need only customer ledger. it works butttttt i don't know how to fetch data from array in table as i shown :(
Pls check output i edit your post.