# Cascaded While Loop in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Trying to generate a customer ledger report for a project I am currently working on. The report is meant to look like the screenshot shown below:

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33819464/need-help-in-creating-simple-ledger-from-mysql-debt-credit-tables)

To achieve this, I have written this T-SQL code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_ReportCustomerLedger 
    @fromDate DATETIME, @toDate DATETIME    
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @customers TABLE (cust_row_Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, AccountId INT)

    INSERT INTO @customers 
        SELECT a.AccountId 
        FROM tbl_Customer a 
        RIGHT JOIN tbl_Invoice b ON a.CustomerId = b.CustomerId
        GROUP BY b.CustomerId, a.AccountId 
        ORDER BY a.AccountId

    DECLARE @customerCount INT = 0

    SELECT @customerCount = COUNT(*) FROM @customers
    DECLARE @i INT = 1

    WHILE(@i <= @customerCount)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @accountId INT

        SELECT @accountId = AccountId 
        FROM @customers 
        WHERE cust_row_Id = @i

        DECLARE @transactions TABLE (trans_row_id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, Amount DECIMAL(18,2), TransactionDate DATE, EntryType INT, TransactionId INT)

       INSERT INTO @transactions 
           SELECT a.Amount, b.TransactionDate, a.EntryType, a.TransactionId 
           FROM tbl_Ledger a 
           LEFT JOIN tbl_Transaction b ON a.TransactionId = b.TransactionId
           WHERE a.AccountId = @accountId 
             AND b.TransactionDate BETWEEN @fromDate AND @toDate
           ORDER BY b.TransactionDate

       DECLARE @transCount INT = 0
       DECLARE @j INT = 0

       SELECT @transCount = COUNT(*) FROM @transactions

       DECLARE @result TABLE (TransactionDate DATE, Dr DECIMAL(18,2), Cr DECIMAL(18,2), Balance DECIMAL(18,2))

       DECLARE @initialBalance DECIMAL(18,2) =  0
       DECLARE @initialDr DECIMAL(18,2) =  0
       DECLARE @initialCr DECIMAL(18,2) =  0

       SELECT @initialDr = SUM(a.Amount) 
       FROM tbl_Ledger a 
       LEFT JOIN tbl_Transaction b ON a.TransactionId = b.TransactionId
       WHERE a.AccountId = @accountId 
         AND b.TransactionDate <= @fromDate 
         AND a.EntryType = 2

       SELECT @initialCr = SUM(a.Amount) 
       FROM tbl_Ledger a 
       LEFT JOIN tbl_Transaction b ON a.TransactionId = b.TransactionId
       WHERE a.AccountId = @accountId AND b.TransactionDate <= @fromDate AND a.EntryType = 1

SET @initialBalance = @initialDr - @initialCr

WHILE(@j<=@transCount)
BEGIN

DECLARE @entryType INT = (SELECT EntryType FROM @transactions WHERE trans_row_id = @j)
DECLARE @amount DECIMAL = (SELECT Amount FROM @transactions WHERE trans_row_id = @j)
DECLARE @transactionDate DATE = (SELECT TransactionDate FROM @transactions WHERE trans_row_id = @j)
DECLARE @dr DECIMAL(18, 0) = 0
DECLARE @cr DECIMAL(18, 0) = 0
DECLARE @balance DECIMAL(18, 0) = 0

IF(@entryType = 2)
BEGIN
SET @dr = @amount
SET @balance = @initialBalance + @dr
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SET @cr = @amount
SET @balance = @initialBalance - @cr
END

INSERT INTO @result SELECT @transactionDate, @dr, @cr, @balance


SET @j = @j + 1
END;

SELECT @initialBalance AS 'Initial Balance';

SELECT * FROM @result;


DELETE FROM @result
DELETE FROM @transactions

SET @i = @i + 1
END;

DELETE FROM @customers


END
GO
```

Issue: after execution the script keep running non-stop with blank data. At every exit I made sure the table variables are cleared or their data deleted.

Comment: Using nested while loops is definitely not the right approach here. But no idea what part(s) of this you need help with.

Comment: @SeanLange what other method will you suggest?

Comment: Set based logic. You should be able to replace the insert statements in the first part with a single insert statement. Then to get the running total there are several better options than loops. But the best way to accomplish that depends on what version of sql server you are using.

Comment: @SeanLange ok. I removed the Delete for the table variables but it kept repeating the same data over and over again.

Comment: Well gosh that is unfortunate. I can't possibly help here. There is no table definitions, no sample data, no desired output. Just a bunch of code that doesn't work. Maybe start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And the look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for some inspiration about how to make this into an answerable question.

Comment: Learn to debug your own code. If your looping is a problem, then remove anything not related to just the looping and add code so that you can see the control variables and how they change (or more likely - do not change). And take this to heart - tsql is not designed to produce "reports". Even **skilled** tsql devs will struggle to produce "pretty" output with only tsql.

Comment: And one more comment - rows in a table have no inherent order. A select statement without an order by clause will generate rows with no defined order. You might see a pattern that you assume is reliable - only to find at a later date that it is not.

Comment: @SMor Took the inner loop and applied your suggestions. Executed separately. Got desired output.

Comment: @SMor Executed the inner loop sp inside the first loop. works fine.

Comment: Aside: Since you are using `insert into ... select ...` you could simply `set @ThingCount = @@RowCount;` in the next statement and not count the rows.

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)